# FACEBOOK PHP SDK v4.0 Allowed memory Issue

Tags: php, facebook, memory, sdk

I'm trying to run the Facebook SDK for PHP v4.0 for the past two days, but without results. I'm not using Composer, but the autoload.php file. I'm getting the following errror message :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 2623910681 bytes)

~ It tries to allocate about 2GB memory, and I'm using a shared hosting, I can't increase the memory_limit more than 256MB...

I'm loading the autoload.php file in this way:

```
session_start();
define( 'ROOT', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
require_once( ROOT . 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php' );
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
```

Is there some solution to this problem? I browsed much on google, there are people facing same issue. Also the amount of memory used doesn't seem reasonable to me.

I hope someone has an idea how to fix this!

Comment: " I'm not using Composer, but the autoload.php file", so i was wondering what command made you this error ?

Comment: I'm loading the autoload.php file in this way:

session_start();

define( 'ROOT', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
require_once( ROOT . 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php' );
use Facebook\FacebookSession;

Comment: Can you try removing the samples provided in the sdk?

Comment: I did remove the sample, but the problem is still there.

Comment: @rain_drops did you solve the problem? I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and upgrading PHP version to 5.6 solved the memory issue.
You must be aware that PHP 5.6 sets the default charset to UTF8.